# Torrent content in Linux

Tags: command-line, bittorrent

How to view/explore a torrent file content using command line in Linux.

I know I can use GUI such as `transmission` or `qbitorrent` ....

This how you can obtain using transmission

**This picture is just a sample and i don't want to steal or copy or whatever you called anyone copyrighted files. this is just a techincal question and this example is just an example. So Don't downvote for this reason**

[image]

but I need to do that using a command line.

Comment: I sure do hope you're not using your torrent client to steal copyrighted content.

Comment: @PatrickCollins Copying is not stealing. Stealing is morally wrong because it removes the original. Copying does not.

Comment: @EMBLEM I'm not trying to support the RIAA, I just think that another example would be more appropriate for this site.

Comment: @EMBLEM removing physical goods decreases their value, copying digital goods whose value is a factor of their scarcity decreases their value. Copyright and author's rights are legal regimes that seek to protect the value of easily-copied goods so that the person who owns or creates those goods can benefit from them. Do we agree?

Comment: @SteveDL To artificially create scarcity where there is none (and in fact where bounty is a natural consequence of the product's existence) is more akin to theft than copying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The Easiest solution** is to use `btshowmetainfo`

First install bittorrent

```
 sudo apt-get install bittorrent
```

Now you can show the torrent content using:

```
btshowmetainfo file.torrent
```

---

---

**Another solution** I've found  **[DumpTorrent](http://ask.xmodulo.com/view-torrent-file-content-linux.html)**

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/dumptorrent/dumptorrent/1.2/dumptorrent-1.2.tar.gz
tar -xvf dumptorrent-1.2.tar.gz
cd dumptorrent-1.2
make
sudo cp dumptorrent /usr/local/bin
```

To show The contents

```
dumptorrent file.torrent
```

---

---

Comment: `dumptorrent` feels lightning-fast compared to `transmission-show` and `aria2c -S`.

Answer (score 29):

You can use `transmission-cli`: `sudo apt-get install transmission-cli`.

This will provide a CLI for torrents. You can show the contents of a torrent file with:

```
transmission-show my-file.torrent
```

To show only files use:

```
transmission-show my-file.torrent | sed -n -e '/FILES/,$p'
```

For easier use add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
function tsf { transmission-show "$1" | sed -n -e '/FILES/,$p'; }
```

You can replace `tsf` with whatever you like and then just use `tsf my-file.torrent`.

Comment: There is no switch  for that, you would have to use e.g. `sed`.

Comment: Nice answer. I prefer if there is some other commands without using `sed`, `awk` and such. If no answer i'll consider to mark yours.

Comment: Added a way to make it a one command only call.

Comment: I still find dumptorrent easy to understand... Try to find a solution neglecting using of `sed`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`lstor`](https://code.google.com/p/pyroscope/wiki/CommandLineTools#lstor) from [`pyroscope/pyrocore`](https://github.com/pyroscope/pyrocore).

Just follow the [installation instructions](http://pyrocore.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) to install the command line tools.

To get the file list use the following command:

```
$ lstor -qo info.name ~/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent
ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use torrenttools.
This tool will also work with the new BitTorrent v2 metafiles and hybrid torrents.

`torrenttools info bittorrent-v2-hybrid-test.torrent`

```
Metafile:         /home/fbdtemme/Documents/project/torrent/torrenttools/tests/resources/bittorrent-v2-hybrid-test.torrent
Protocol version: v1 + v2 (hybrid)
Infohash:         v1: 8c9a2f583949c757c32e085413b581067eed47d0
                  v2: d8dd32ac93357c368556af3ac1d95c9d76bd0dff6fa9833ecdac3d53134efabb
Piece size:       512 KiB (524288 bytes)
Created by:       libtorrent
Created on:       2020-06-03 08:45:06 UTC
Private:          false
Name:             bittorrent-v1-v2-hybrid-test
Source:           
Comment:          

Announces:

Files:
bittorrent-v1-v2-hybrid-test
  ├── [6.23 MiB] Darkroom (Stellar, 1994, Amiga ECS) HQ.mp4
  ├── [19.6 MiB] Spaceballs-StateOfTheArt.avi
  ├── [ 326 MiB] cncd_fairlight-ceasefire_(all_falls_down)-1080p.mp4
  ├── [58.8 MiB] eld-dust.mkv
  ├── [ 265 MiB] fairlight_cncd-agenda_circling_forth-1080p30lq.mp4
  ├── [42.5 MiB] meet the deadline - Still _ Evoke 2014.mp4
  ├── [61.0   B] readme.txt
  ├── [25.1 MiB] tbl-goa.avi
  └── [ 111 MiB] tbl-tint.mpg

  854.06 MiB in 0 directories, 9 files
```

You can install torrenttools from this repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fbdtemme/torrenttools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install torrenttools
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of this tool.

For more information see:

https://github.com/fbdtemme/torrenttools

https://fbdtemme.github.io/torrenttools